# Foundation 5: call js function from topbar dropdown anchor

Tags: javascript, html, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

Maybe I am being stupid here but I cannot figure out how to respond to a Foundation 5 TopBar dropdown selection with a javascript function. I would like to select a theme for a library I use. To set the theme I need to call a js function.

What I have is:

```
<div class="fixed">
<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation">
    <section class="top-bar-section">
        <!-- Right Nav Section -->
    <ul class="right">
        <li class="has-dropdown">
            <a href="#">Theme</a>
            <ul class="dropdown" id="theme-dropdown">
                <li><a href="#">Light</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </section>
</nav>
</div>
```

these are of course contained in the topbar `<nav>`, etc and the dropdown on the topbar works great in basic HTML mode.

What I am struggling with is how do I make the 2 `<li><a>` elements (light and dark themes) call my JavaScript function `setTheme(themeName)` when they are clicked?

I cannot seem to find any examples where someone wants to call js from a topbar rather than a URL.

Comment: added Foundation 5-specific markup as I was not explicit enough that non-Foundation HTML seems fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you aren't using a JavaScript framework? If you are, you should investigate how that framework can help you handle events. Otherwise, here are some ideas:

**1. `onclick` attribute**

So long as your `setTheme` function is defined globally you can call it from within the `onclick` attribute of a list item.

```js
var span = document.querySelector('span');
function setTheme (themeName) {
  span.innerText = themeName;
}
```

```html
<li onclick="setTheme('light')">Light</li>
<li onclick="setTheme('dark')">Dark</li>

Selected theme: <span>none</span>
```

**2. `addEventListener` method**

If your function `setTheme` is not global, target the element using your preferred approach within scope of the function and attach an event handler to the `'click'` event using `addEventListener`.

```js
var listElems = document.querySelectorAll('li');
[].forEach.call(listElems, function (elem) {
  elem.addEventListener('click', function () {
    console.log("HI");
    setTheme(this.dataset.value);
  });
});

var span = document.querySelector('span');
function setTheme (themeName) {
  span.innerText = themeName;
}
```

```html
<li data-value="light">Light</li>
<li data-value="dark">Dark</li>

Selected theme: <span>none</span>
```

Comment: thx for the quick reply. I want to say that I have tried your #1 and it didn't work. I will give it another shot, though. I wonder if something in the `foundation.min.js` could somehow block the `onclick`?

Comment: @warspite I have amended the post to contain examples. As you can see, they both work fine. :-)

Comment: I tried again and it's not working as you show above. I can only think that Foundation is getting in the way.

Comment: @warspite I doubt that is the case. Here are JSFiddles of the examples with Foundation: [first](http://jsfiddle.net/sdgluck/g51drjh8/), [second](http://jsfiddle.net/sdgluck/4aL1zob6/).

Comment: (As in the first example on JSFiddle, try defining the function on window: `window.setTheme = function () { ... }`.)

Comment: again, ty so much for your help. I truly appreciate it. I added some markup to the OP as I think its relevant and I probably simplified it to much before. I have tried your examples and all work as expected in the simple form but do not when I make them into a Foundation topbar.

Comment: I was successful in making this work. It was user error in that I was not properly initializing the Foundation JS. I have marked your answer as correct @sdgluck as it was correct after I did this 1 step. tyvm

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being a stupid mistake on my part as I was not initializing the Foundation JS with this...

```
<script>
    $(document).foundation();
</script>
```

Once I did, the solutions @sdgluck gave were bang on.